# Rails partial renders in console network response but not in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partials

I am trying to have my partial display search results in a rails view. When I check my console > network > preview, I see my partial rendered with the data I need but it doesn't display in my view.

Here's my app/controllers/searchs_controller.rb

```
def nearby_guides
@address = params[:address]
initial_array = @address.split(',')
city = initial_array[0]
state = initial_array[1].split(' ')
final_state = state[0]
country = initial_array[2]
@result = User.where("city = ?", city)
respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render :partial => '/searchs/result', object: @result}
end
end
```

Here's my views/searchs/_result.html.erb

```
<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>

<% if @result %>
    <% @result.each do |r| %>
        <p><%= r.firstname %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then in my views/searchs/new.html.erb

```
<%= render 'result' %>
```

This is the response I see in my console > network > preview

```
HELLO WORLD

Kevin
```

Which is exactly the response I expected but again, it doesn't display in the view. I've looked over stack overflow with no luck. Thanks so much for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is your issue: `format.html {render :partial =>`

When you are rendering the result of an action as html - it needs to be a whole view, not just a partial.

Rendering partials is generally reserved for AJAX queries - where you need only part of the page and your javascript will insert it into the page in the right place. so either you need javascript, or you need to do something like: `render :new`